# How do I refer to a class with a Symbol in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, hash, symbols

I want to make a Hash whose keys refer to the symbol of a class and the value some array which has, for example, colours that refer to that specific class. As of now, my implementation is this one:

```
module DomesticAnimal
    attr_accessor :name

    def eat(food)
        puts "Eating #{food}"
    end
end

module AnimalColours #Lo separo para realizar más abstracción
    @@colours = {
        :dog => ["White", "Grey", "Black", "Brown"],
        :cat => ["White", "Black"],
    }

    def self.hasColour(type, colour)
        if @@colours[type] != nil
            @@colours[type].each do |x|
                return true unless x != colour
            end
        end
        return false
    end
end

class Dog
    include DomesticAnimal

    def initialize(name, colour)
        @name = name

        if AnimalColours.hasColour(:dog, colour)
            @colour = colour
        else
            raise "Colour error"
        end
    end

    def goOut(place)
        puts "#{name} when out for a walk to #{place}"
    end
end

dog = Dog.new("Juan", "Black")

dog.goOut("the park")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refer to a class with a symbol"? You can use anything as a hash key, including a class.

Comment: Design-wise, it doesn't really make sense that `AnimalColours` would contain the code for which animal can be which color. That code should go in the respective animal class. `AnimalColours` should only contain code generic to _all_ colors.

Comment: Why convert to symbols? Strings will work equally well in this case and not that it will have a huge impact but symbols will consume more memory as they are frozen and will never be picked up by GC. Although since they are in a class_variable it wont matter much since that won't be GC'd either. Good new though for those who care seesm 2.2.0 might actually [GC Symbols created outside the C-level](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9634)

Comment: @Max, I wanted to have like a container with all the colours of the animals, so an animal class could pick its own from that class, because in fact, the colour of the animal is something extra, it's not really hooked to the characteristics of the class

Comment: Why do you want to constantly convert back and forth between classes and symbols? Why don't you just use the classes as keys?

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's what i'm trying to do, use the classes as keys

Comment: But you aren't using the classes as keys, you are using symbols as keys.

Comment: Right, I posted my code so that you could see how i was implementing it, my question is how to rewrite this using classes as symbols

Answer (score 0):

You could use strings as the keys to the hash instead of symbols.
You can access the name of a class (string) with `class.name`.

I suppose if you wanted them to be symbols, you could call `class.name.to_sym` and have the keys be, for example, `:Dog`. Note that the symbol after the leading colon is identical to the class name.

Comment: They can use the classes themselves as hash keys (if they declare the classes first).

Comment: I wanted to use symbols because, as i've been told, they're faster than strings regarding to iterations, for example

Comment: @user3452637 that kind of micro-optimization is not what Ruby is about. Regardless, there are also cases where symbols are worse than strings. You need a better reason to prefer them other than it _maybe_ being faster.